# How does one associate Google Analytics with a particular authenticated user?

Tags: google-analytics

What method would you use to associate tracking information in Google Analytics with a particular named user?

I want to be able to do custom reports, and ultimately drill down on usage by user.

**EDIT**
I was thinking that perhaps the [EventTracking API](http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/eventTrackerOverview.html) would be able to help somehow.

Also, referring to [this documentation](http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/eventTrackerGuide.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could add the user's username as a tracking/segmentation) variable...

```
pageTracker._setVar(username);
```

You can only use one _setVar per page, though...

http://www.google.com/support/analytics/bin/answer.py?answer=57045

http://groups.google.com/group/analytics-help-basics/browse_thread/thread/07e29dc610050971

Comment: Yes, I found this too. Did you do this successfully?

Comment: No - I remembered seeing it when I was playing with getting GA set up for our environment, but we didn't end up wanting anything like that so I never got to try it. Seemed like it did what you wanted, though.

Comment: we found it more use for tracking logged in users vs not in general, they tend to use different parts of the site

Comment: Analytic TOS doesn't allow to track personal information, but I'm not sure if a username fits in that restriction. "7. PRIVACY . You will not (and will not allow any third party to) use the Service to track or collect personally identifiable information of Internet users..."

Answer (score 0):

Since Google Analytics isn't aware of users who are logged into your site you'd have to do that sort of tracking within your site's software itself. If there isn't some sort of plugin or extension out there already you'll probably have to write one yourself that keeps track of what your users do when their logged in.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want [Google Analytics - Custom Variables](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/gaTrackingCustomVariables).  You can set five variables per page, and there is support for variables you set persisting over session and cookie (aka "visitor") lifetime.  Take note of the rules for overwriting previous values based upon slot and scope; the documentation explains this with some examples.  You should probably include something in a click-wrapped privacy policy about tracking individual users this way; it's somewhat invasive, depending on the purpose of your website.

```
_gaq.push(['_setCustomVar',
    1,          // Slot number: [1-5], inclusive.  Required.
    'Username', // Custom variable name.  Required.
    username,   // Custom variable value.  Required.
    2           // Scope: 
                // 1 = visitor/cookie-level, 2 = session-level, 3 = page-level.  
                // Optional, default=3.
]);
```

Answer (score -1):

http://www.highlyrelevant.com/2011/03/25/how-to-add-edit-google-analytics-users-to-your-account/

This post was really helpful for me and my team. Not only does it show how to add users, but it also tells you how to edit existing users that aren't setup correctly.

Thanks!
Phil

Comment: This isn't about *tracking* user information - this is about setting up users to *access* your Google Analytics account